# Grouping and replacing similar trigrams in python using fuzzywuzzy or some other package

Tags: python, pandas, similarity, fuzzywuzzy

I have a set of trigrams lets say

```
 ID |        Trigram         | Frequency 
  1 | great customer service |        10 
  2 | customer service great |         8 
  3 | good customer service |         6 
  4 | have some parking      |         5 
  5 | some more parking      |         2
```

I want to do a fuzzy match across all the trigrams and replace the similar ones with the one with the highest frequency. For example, above table should become

```
 ID |        Trigram         | Frequency 
  1 | great customer service |        10 
  2 | great customer service |         8 
  3 | great customer service |         6
  4 | have some parking      |         5 
  5 | have some parking      |         2
```

I'm using fuzzywuzzy package to calculate similarity but can't figure out how to do replacement. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is involve the NLTK

Comment: For example *customer service not great*